# Query which LineString in GeoJson MultiLineString

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geojson

Given I have a public bus route which consist of 2 major bus stops. The route divided into 2 sub routes, interconnect in circular but both have the same route number.

So I store the `routes` in `GeoJson` `MultiLineString` (contain 2 LineStrings in a `GeoJson`). The `route` document look something like:

```
{
  "routeName": "A123",
  "route": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [102.0, 2.0] ],// 1st sub route
        [ [102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [100.0, 0.0] ] // 2nd sub route
      ]
  }
}
```

Now if query by using `$near`, I can get the whole nearest `route` document. However I want to know the nearest sub route or `LineString`, either the first one or the second one.

Is it possible and if so, is it possible to get nearby route and the sub route in one query?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB cannot "break up" a GeoJSON object in order to match the "nearest point" like you want to do. Your problem is therefore likely more suited to another stucture which will alows each "stop" to be considered independantly rather than it just being represented as a point on a "LineString".

One very efficient way to use this in queries is this:

```js
{
  "routename": "A123",
  "stops": [
    { 
      "type": "out",
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [100.0,0.0]
      }
    },
    { 
      "type": "out",
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [101.0,1.0]
      }
    },
    { 
      "type": "return",
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0,2.0]
      }
    },
    { 
      "type": "return",
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [103.0,3.0]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which breaks down each "stop" on the route to a distinct "point", as well as keeping the route "type" denoting whether the stop is on the "out" or "return" leg of the trip.

Then you can run this aggregation query using [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) in order to match and project the "nearest point" from the array entries. The next stage compares that matched location to each of the "stops" in the array, in order to extract the leg of the route which that stop belongs to:

```js
db.routes.aggregate([ 
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [103.0, 2.0]
    },
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "spherical": true,
    "includeLocs": "loc"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "routeName": 1,
    "distance": 1,
    "route": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "matchedStop": {
            "$setDifference": [
              { "$map": {
                "input": "$stops",
                "as": "stop",
                "in": {
                  "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$$stop.location", "$loc" ] },
                    "$$stop",
                    false
                  ]
                }
              }},
              [false]
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
              "input": "$stops",
              "as": "stop",
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$setEquals": [
                    { "$map": { "input": ["A"], "as": "el", "in": "$$stop.type" } },
                    "$$matchedStop.type"
                  ]},
                  { 
                    "type": "$$stop.type",
                    "location": "$$stop.location",
                    "nearest": {
                      "$eq": [ "$$stop.location", "$loc" ]
                    }
                  },
                  false
                ]
              }
            }},
            [false]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which will give you this type of output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ee6c0a2343a0d2e1650e28"),
    "distance" : 111251.03086891436,
    "route" : [
            {
                    "type" : "return",
                    "location" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [
                                    102,
                                    2
                            ]
                    },
                    "nearest" : true
            },
            {
                    "type" : "return",
                    "location" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [
                                    103,
                                    3
                            ]
                    },
                    "nearest" : false
            }
    ]
}
```

This is mostly heavy use of [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to extract the elements that are required. So the first case is to extract the matched element that has been identified in the "includeLocs" return from `$geoNear`. This then allows you to reprocess the array and filter out only the "elements" that contain the same "type" for the leg of the route, and for added niceness we also flag when array member was in fact the "nearest" match.

Particularly with the route "type" to match, the returned variable from the earlier `$map` is in fact an array. So you can only realy compare an array with another "array", which is why `$map` is again used against the singular field value, in order to turn it into an array itself:

```js
{ "$setEquals": [
  { "$map": { "input": ["A"], "as": "el", "in": "$$stop.type" } },
  "$$matchedStop.type"
]},
```

So that is what that part is all about, and of course [**`$setEquals`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) tests both arrays to see if they are in fact the same.

Other things in here are [**`$let`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) in order to make getting the "matchedStop" a bit more accessible, and the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) essentially filters out any returned values of `false` from the tests being done on array members via the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator.

Of course, the alternative here is to basically just separate every "stop" into it's own document within a collection, and then run one query to find the "nearest" document and another query to find the same "route" and other stops on the same "leg" of that route in your return information. But this will still be self contained in the one document and match and will be pretty efficient, especially for multiple "route" matches.

Comment: Ok, almost there but I do have waypoints data between stops that might improve the 'nearby' result. So it seems like I need to update the new structure to include indexed `stops.waypoints` as `LineString` to be used by `$geoNear` while keeping the `stops.location` `Point` unindexed to be used by `$project` am I right?

Comment: @CallMeLaNN I cannot write your project for you, but just show you what cannot work and what can. It is not possible to use "LineString" for your purpose because you want each "node" as a location you need to to match to specifically. This is what the answer shows you.

Comment: I understand now that I can't extract `Point` from the `MultiLineString` and `LineString`. Since it is acceptable to extract the smallest `LineString` between two stops, not to say each node, it should be ok and I can get which 'sub route' and the 'stop'. +1 for mention about aggregation framework. Thx for your time.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN LineString will likely not work for you as you still won't be able to identify the "stop" which you are nearest to. The only benefit of `$geoNear` with aggregation here is where the content is an "array" as shown above then you can match the "array entry" for the nearest point. Otherwise use documents. But you cannot get that data out of a `MultiLineString` or `LineString`. Hence the lesson.

Comment: Let me clarify my thought after I got the idea from your example. The `LineString` here refer to waypoints between stops, not the list of stops. I will query which stop, not a single waypoint 'node'. I follow the same way as you suggest: An array of stops contain a location `Point` but I add waypoints `LineString`. Let me try it out. Worst case I will create another document with multiple queries.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN You seem to missing the point here. Your current storage does not work, so that is the point I have basically made. You need to separate out the things you at least need as a result to either A. Separate array entries or B. separate documents. Be that of "point" or "LineString" is not the point here, but rather that you cannot get the information from your "MultiLineString" at current. That is what the answer says, as well as IMHO a "Point" has more flexibility as per the example shown. A different choice on storage does not make another answer.